# readingskill data set was not found

Tags: r

i have  downloaded all necessary  packages in R , but i could not access  ReadingSkill  dataset, when i am calling

```
 print(head(readingSkills))
```

> Error in head(readingSkills) : object 'readingSkills' not found

before i have installed package  party

```
> install.packages("party")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Dato/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/party_1.3-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 898440 bytes (877 KB)
downloaded 877 KB

package ‘party’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Dato\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpon2RVm\downloaded_packages
```

so how can i access  readingSkills   data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:`head(party::readingSkills)` I'm using `party` 1.3-1

```
 nativeSpeaker age shoeSize    score
1           yes   5 24.83189 32.29385
2           yes   6 25.95238 36.63105
3            no  11 30.42170 49.60593
4           yes   7 28.66450 40.28456
5           yes  11 31.88207 55.46085
6           yes  10 30.07843 52.83124
```

In general, you can do:

```
data(readingSkills,package = "party")
```

Otherwise I suspect you didn't call:

```
library(party)
```

Comment: library(party) i have done, thanks   now it works,  thank you

Comment: what about  function ctree?  i am talking about decision tree

Comment: I'm sorry I am unable to clearly get the question. Maybe you could try to type `?ctree` and follow the examples in there. Otherwise, you can ask a new question with a sample of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply need to call `data(readingSkills)` as per below, although strangely enough I was also able to get it work without that as well. Worth a shot...

```r
# install.packages('party')
library(party)
#> Loading required package: grid
#> Loading required package: mvtnorm
#> Loading required package: modeltools
#> Loading required package: stats4
#> Loading required package: strucchange
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
#> Loading required package: sandwich

# Need to run this first
data(readingSkills)

print(head(readingSkills))
#>   nativeSpeaker age shoeSize    score
#> 1           yes   5 24.83189 32.29385
#> 2           yes   6 25.95238 36.63105
#> 3            no  11 30.42170 49.60593
#> 4           yes   7 28.66450 40.28456
#> 5           yes  11 31.88207 55.46085
#> 6           yes  10 30.07843 52.83124
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>